# Finding string length and append with another column in dictionary format from csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

My dataframe -
[image]

Basically
-I want to append house and district column

- Then find the string length for both columns; in this case House 263 --> (0, 8), dhaka (10,14)
- also, attach their associated labels (label1 column and label2)
- doing it for all the rows

My expected output format is My expected output- `[('House 263 dhaka', {'entities': [[(0, 8)], 'holding_number'], [(10,14), 'district']})`

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this list comprehension:

```
>>> [(k, {'entities': [[[0, len(k.rpartition(' ')[0]) - 1], v['label1']], [(k.rfind(' ') + 1, len(k) - 1), v['label2']]]}) for k, v in df.set_index(['house', 'district']).set_axis(df[['house', 'district']].agg(' '.join, axis=1)).to_dict('index').items()]
[('House 163 dhaka', {'entities': [[[0, 8], 'holding_number'], [(10, 14), 'district']]}), ('House 31 comilla', {'entities': [[[0, 7], 'holding_number'], [(9, 15), 'district']]}), ('House 193/A chittagong', {'entities': [[[0, 10], 'holding_number'], [(12, 21), 'district']]})]
>>>
```